# Bing Maps outputting wrong Coordinates C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, latitude-longitude, bing-maps, geopoints

Observe the coordinates in the map screenshot. The longitude should be a negative value no? Does anyone know what's going on here? Here's the code I use to label that target:

```
private void TargetMap_MapTapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)
    {
        TargetMap.MapElements.Remove(TargetMapIcon);

        TargetMap.MapElements.Add(TargetMapIcon);
        var Lat = args.Location.Position.Latitude;
        var Lon = args.Location.Position.Longitude;

        TargetMapIcon.Title = Lat + ", " + Lon;
        BasicGeoposition TargetPosition = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = Lat, Longitude = Lon };
        Geopoint TargetPoint = new Geopoint(TargetPosition);
        //TargetMap.Center = TargetPoint;
        TargetMapIcon.Location = TargetPoint;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that longitude in/near New York City NY should be -73.95 degrees or thereabouts, certainly not +73.95 degrees. Can't help with why/how Bing Maps appears to be losing the minus sign.

Comment: How does the definition of TargetMapIcon look like? Does it have a template that you could show us?

Comment: public MapIcon TargetMapIcon = new MapIcon() { Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/UI/Icons/bullseye.png")) };

Comment: view this video to see it in context
https://www.facebook.com/brett.ezra/videos/vb.100011946949336/234391300302433/?type=2&theater